# Comparing two CSV Files Based on Specific Data in two Columns

Tags: python, csv

I was encouraged to step out of my comfort zone and use python with little to no experience and now I'm stuck.  I'm trying to compare two CSV files (fileA.csv and fileB.csv), and append any missing user rows to fileA.csv from fileB.csv.  The only fields I can compare with are user's first and last names (in this case, it's row[0] and row[2] from each file).

From my understanding, you cannot append information to a file that you currently have open so I'm open to suggestions without having to create a third file (if possible).  Below has me on the right track, but there's a lot of data so I'll need a loop.  Please help.

```
import csv
reader1 = csv.reader(open('fileA', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
row1 = reader1.next()
reader2 = csv.reader(open('fileB', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
row2 = reader2.next()


##For Loop...

        if (row1[0] == row2[0]) and (row1[2] == row2[2]):
                ## Compare next 
        else:
                ## Append entire row to fileA.csv
```

---

Example FileA.csv:

```
John,Thomas,Doe,some,other,stuff
Jane, ,Smith,some,other,stuff
```

Example FileB.csv:

```
John, ,Doe,other,personal,data
Jane,Elizabeth,Smith,other,personal,data
Robin,T,Williams,other,personal,data
```

The only row that should append from FileB to FileA is Robin's complete Row so that FileA looks like:

DesiredResult_FileA:

```
John,Thomas,Doe,some,other,stuff
Jane, ,Smith,some,other,stuff
Robin,T,Williams,other,personal,data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the information found in file A in memory first, in a set.

Then, *reopen* file A in append mode, and loop over file B. Any name from B not found in the set, can then be added to file A:

```
csv_dialect = dict(delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
names = set()
with open('fileA', 'rb') as file_a:
    reader1 = csv.reader(file_a, **csv_dialect)
    next(reader1)
    for row in reader1:
        names.add((row[0], row[2]))

# `names` is now a set of all names (taken from columns 0 and 2) found in file A.

with open('fileA', 'ab') as file_a, open('fileB', 'rb') as file_b:
    writer = csv.writer(file_a, **csv_dialect)
    reader2 = csv.reader(file_b, **csv_dialect)
    next(reader2)
    for row in reader2:
        if (row[0], row[2]) not in names:
            # This row was not present in file A, add it.
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The combined `with` line requires Python 2.7 or newer. In earlier Python versions, simply nest the two statements:

```
with open('fileA', 'ab') as file_a:
    with open('fileB', 'rb') as file_b:
        # etc.
```

Comment: Is that syntax correct?        

file_a, open('fileB', 'rb') as file_b:

Comment: @justin: It is in Python 2.7. In earlier versions, just nest the two (so make them separate lines and indent one level extra).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), that might help you handle csv files easier, and seems its more readable:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('FileA.csv', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('FileB.csv', header=None)


for i in df2.index:
    # Don't append if that row is existed in FileA
    if i in df1.index:
        if df1.ix[i][0] == df2.ix[i][0] and df1.ix[i][2] == df2.ix[i][2]: continue

    df1 = df1.append(df2.ix[i])

df1.to_csv('FileA.csv', index=None, header=None)
```